# jQuery slideDown not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I wish to animate a div to make it appear and slide down with jQuery.

I have got my script to work where you hover over an image and another div slides in, should the user leave the mouse hover, the div will slide up and disappear.

**Problem:**

The first time i hover over the image, nothing happens. I have to leave my mouse and hover over it a second time for the effect to start working, I dont get why this is???

**jQuery:**

```
function show_action(){
    $(function(){
        $(".action").hide();
        $(".logo").hover(
            function(){ $(".action").slideDown(); },
            function(){ $(".action").slideUp(); }
        );
    });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#action_text{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center_container">
  <div class="action" id="action_text"><span>Click To Upload</span></div>
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" onmouseover="show_action();"> 
</div>
```

Comment: have u got entire code. may be with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling function `show_action` as `onhover="show_action()` remove that and move the rest code outside function wrapping, otherwise the **[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** event handler will only bind after the first hover. additionally use **[`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to clear the animation queue

```js
$(function() {
  $(".action").hide();
  $(".logo").hover(
    function() {
      $(".action").stop().slideDown();
    },
    function() {
      $(".action").stop().slideUp();
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=logo>Hover here</div>
<div class=action>content<br>here</div>
```

**Update :** You can remove `$(".action").hide();` by adding following css

```
.action {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: @JimmyDoe : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `.hide()` on the `.action` element. Just give it `display: none` in your css, so that it will not show when the page loads. That way, you don't need the `.stop()` to clear the animation queue, and it also prevents a 'flicker' effect where your `.action` element will show up when the page loads for a brief moment until `.hide()` gets called.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.logo').hover(
    function() {
      $(".action").slideDown();
    },
    function() {
      $(".action").slideUp();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.action {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="logo">LOGO</span>
</div>

<div class="action">
  <span>Action</span>
</div>
```